# Perform click on random list element using Espresso

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to perform click on random list item using espresso. I know there's a way to click on adapter at specified position, but how can I get size of list?

Comment: `adapter.getCount()`? .. and then generate the random number between 0 and the `count`.

Comment: then how can you get the adapter using espresso?

Comment: I see... well, one (hacky) way would be to have a public method in your activity, something like `public int getListSize() { return listSize; }`, and then in your test you could call `getActivity().getListSize();` But, yes, making your activities return the size of the adapter is not very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I know by the time i'm answering this it's pretty late but just for a future reference.
You can define a custom view action which is something like this

```
private static final class ScrollToRandomPosition implements ViewAction {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") @Override public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
        return allOf(isAssignableFrom(RecyclerView.class), isDisplayed());
    }

    @Override public String getDescription() {
        return "scroll RecyclerView to random position ";
    }

    @Override public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
        Random ran = new Random();
        uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(ran.nextInt(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()));
    }
}
```

So you can call this externally

```
public static ViewAction scrollToRandomPosition(){
    return new ScrollToRandomPosition();
}
```